# Minimum number of steps to convert one integer to another

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Recently i came across a problem, given 2 integers A and B, we need to convert A to B in minimum number of steps.
We can perform following operations on A:

- If A is odd, decrease by 1
- If A is even, increase by 1
- Multiply A(even or odd) by 2
- if A is even, divide by 2

again, we have to find the minimum number of steps needed to convert A to B.

The constraints are *0 < A, B < 10^18*

My approach:
I tried to solve the problem using Breadth First Search, adding all the possible reachable numbers from a step into a queue, but it fails on higher constraints i.e. time outs.

Can anyone suggest a faster alternative?

**EDIT: A is not necessarily less than B**

Comment: Think about the numbers in binary and think about what the operations do to the binary representation of the numbers.

Comment: ... and use only one programming language for the solution.

Comment: Can you kindly give any reference link for this problem

Comment: @deHaar sorry but why cant i use more than one? i know all 3 of them, in whichever implementation is easier, i'll go for it.

Comment: @sweetsecret, can you give me the link to the problem?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire am afraid there's no link, the problem isn't online.

Comment: I meant don't use all three (or more) in parallel, but if you know them all very well, then do what you want ;-)  This was an allusion to the many tags, because on SO you should actually choose one per question.

Comment: Another hint: It can be proven that the optimal answer always consists of a sequence of divisions and subtractions followed by a sequence of multiplications and additions.

Comment: Consider the tags to be AND not OR. You've effectively asked for a program that is written in Java, Python, and C++. Not what you wanted.

Comment: @BessieTheCow can you take the pain of providing the implementation/psued? can't figure out much.

Comment: do you only need the *count* of operations, or the *list* of operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of available operations is symmetric: 2 sets of operations, each the opposite of the other:

- the last bit can be flipped
- the number can be shifted left one position or right one position if the low bit is `0`.

Hence it takes the same number of operations to go from `A` to `B` or from `B` to `A`.

Going from `A` to `B` takes at most the number of operations to go from `A` to `0` plus the number of operations to go from `B` to `0`. These operations strictly decrease the values of `A` and `B`. If along the way an intermediary value can be reached from both `A` and `B`, there is no need to go all the way to `0`.

Here is a simple function that performs the individual steps on `A` and `B` and stops as soon as this common number is found:

```py
def num_ops(a, b):
    # compute the number of ops to transform a into b
    # by symmetry, the same number of ops is needed to transform b into a
    count = 0
    while a != b:
        if a > b:
            if (a & 1) != 0:
                a -= 1
            else:
                a >>= 1
        else:
            if (b & 1) != 0:
                b -= 1
            else:
                b >>= 1
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: This solution is not correct. For instance a=3, b=1. Solution should be 1, but this function returns 2.

Comment: @trincot: How do you go from `3` to `1` in a single step? A is odd so you must first decrement A and then shift it right.

Comment: You're right, I missed the condition that division is not allowed when A is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have the following operations:

1. flip the lowest bit
2. shift bits to the left or to the right

Assume, you have `A == 0`, how you would construct `B`? Right, you flip the lower bit one by one and shift the number to the left, for example if `B == 5`, which is 0x0101, you will need 2 flips and 2 shifts.

Now, we have to deal with the case when `A != 0` -- in this case you have to turn the lower bit to `0` and shift right to clean up the mess. For example, if you have `A == 32`, which is 0x0100000 and you want to get 5 (0x0101), you have to do three shifts to the right, then flip the lower bit and you're done.

So, all you have to do is to:

1. count how many flips/r-shifts you have to do until the highest bit of A is equal to the highest bit of B.
2. then count how many flips/r-shifts you need to clean up the rest
3. count how many flips/left-shifts you need to rebuild the lower part of B.

---

ok, a few hours passed, here's the solution. First a useful function, that says how many ops we need to create a number:

```
def bit_count(num) :
    # the number of non-zero bits in a number
    return bin(num).count('1')

def num_ops(num) :
    # number of shifts + number of flips
    return num.bit_length() + bit_count(num)
```

Now, well, assume A > B, because otherwise we can swap them while keeping the number of the operations the same. Here's how far we have to shift `A` to make it start from the same bit as `B`:

```
needed_shifts = A.bit_length() - B.bit_length()
```

while doing that we need to flip a few bits:

```
mask = (1 << (needed_shifts+1)) - 1
needed_flips = bit_count(A & mask)
```

Now we count how many ops are required to clean `A` and rebuild `B`:

```
A >>= needed_shifts
clean_shifts = (A & ~B).bit_length()
clean_flips = bit_count(A & ~B)
rebuild_shifts = (B & ~A).bit_length()
rebuild.flips = bit_count(B & ~A)
```

Finally we sum up all together:

```
result_ops = needed_shifts + needed_flips + max(clean_shifts,rebuild_shifts) * 2 + clean_flips + rebuils_flips
```

That's all, folks! =)

Comment: @sweetsecret updated the answer with the solution code (python)

Comment: I'm afraid the number of steps needed to *clean* `A` and *rebuild* `B` are miscalculated: it only depends on the low order bits of `A`, regardless of the corresponding bits of `B`, similarly the rebuild_ops should only depend on the low order bits of `B`. For example converting `0b101` to `0b111` should take `0 + 1 + num_ops(0b000) + num_ops(0b010)` -> `4` but I don't see how to improve on this 5 step solution: dec, shr, inc, shl, inc.

Comment: @chqrlie I agree about miscalculation of the steps, but my mistake was a bit different. The things you're talking about, "regardless of corresponding bits of B" is a bit off. Let's imagine A=0x1011 1101 and B=0x1011 0010, we can have `A&~B=0x0000 1101` and we have to rebiult the lower 4 bits only, because the upper 4 are the same.

Comment: @chqrlie anyway, maybe we were talking about the same thing. I have changed code a bit, now the flips are calculated separately, but shifts are `max(A,B)*2` because we have to move both ways no matter if there are bits or not, so we take the max and multiply by 2.

Comment: i think this is also a correct approach, thank you very much.

Comment: @lenik: In your `A=0x1011 1101` and `B=0x1011 0010` example, the lower 4 bits need to be rebuilt, but it does not mean you shift by 4, only 3+3 shifts are needed and 2+1+1 flips. `A&~B` can be used to compute the shift count, but is irrelevant to compute the number of flips.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be optimised using dynamic programming.

I wrote the following code taking few things into consideration:

1. The infinite recursion should be avoided carefully by putting up base conditions. For eg: if A=0 and B<0, then no answer exists.
2. If the function `convert(A, B)` is called for more than 1 times into recursion and answer for the state (A, B) is not previously calculated, then recursion is terminated as no answer exists for this case. For eg: (80, 100) -> (160, 100) -> (80->100) -> (160, 100) -> ........

This is done by maintaining the count of each state into a map and defining the maximum recursive calls limit (3 in the following program) for the same state of DP.

The map `dp` maintains the answer for each state (A, B) and the map `iterationsCount` maintains the count of number of times the same state `(A, B)` is called.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <utility> 
#include <iterator> 
#include <map>
#include <set> 
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

typedef long long int LL;

std::map<std::pair<LL, LL>, LL> dp;

std::map<std::pair<LL, LL>, int > iterationsCount;

LL IMPOSSIBLE = (LL)1e9;

LL MAX_RECURSION_LIMIT = 3;

LL convert(LL a, LL b) 
{ 
//std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<std::endl;

    // To avoid infinite recursion:
        if(iterationsCount.find(std::make_pair(a, b))!=iterationsCount.end() &&
        iterationsCount[std::make_pair(a,b)] > MAX_RECURSION_LIMIT &&
        dp.find(std::make_pair(a,b))==dp.end()){
            return IMPOSSIBLE;
        }

    // Maintaining count of each state(A, B)
        iterationsCount[std::make_pair(a, b)]++;

    LL value1, value2, value3, value4, value5;

    value1 = value2 = value3 = value4 = value5 = IMPOSSIBLE;

    if(dp.find(std::make_pair(a,b)) != dp.end()){
        return dp[std::make_pair(a, b)];
    }

    // Base Case 
    if(a==0 && b<0){
        return IMPOSSIBLE;
    }

    // Base Case 
    if (a == b) 
        return 0; 

    //Conditions
    if (a%2 == 1){

        if(a < b){

            value1 = 1 + convert(2*a, b);

        }

        else if(a > b){

            value2 = 1 + convert(a-1, b); 

        }
    }
    else{

        if(a < b){


            value3 = 1 + convert(a*2, b);



            value4 = 1 + convert(a+1, b);

        }

        else if(a > b){

            value5 = 1 + convert(a/2, b);

        }
    }

    LL ans = std::min(value1, std::min(value2, std::min(value3, std::min(value4, value5))));

    dp[std::make_pair(a, b)] = ans;

    return ans;
} 

int main(){

    LL ans = convert(10, 95);
    if(ans == IMPOSSIBLE){
        std::cout<<"Impossible";
    }else{
        std::cout<<ans;
    }
    return 0;
}
```